# Как получить статус/описание профиля участника Discord-сервера с помощью бота?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Пишу бота на disnake, хочу получить статусы/описания профиля участников, а точнее - раздел "Обо мне", своего сервера, в документации ничего не нашёл, нагуглить не получилось.
Ответ из discord.py тоже принимается

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.guild.members[0])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Подкорректировал вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны сравнить оба статуса. затем отправьте сообщение на канал, используя его id

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
if before.status is discord.Status.offline and after.status is discord.Status.online:
    print('was offline then online')
    channel = client.get_channel(ID_HERE)  # notification channel
    await channel.send(f'{after.name} is now {after.status}')
```

Comment: Вы не поняли суть вопроса, я неправильно донёс  видимо. Мне нужно получить текст из раздела "Обо мне".

Answer (score 0):

Ни disnake, ни discord.py не предоставляют такой возможности